# Adding an image publishing node to the android_tutorial_image_transport

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am wondering about how to add an image publisher to original image_transport tutorial project in order to publish the images from Android camera?

Here are some ideas I've tried but have not succeeded:

- Use RosCameraPreviewView (like the android_camera_tutorial did) inside the MainActivity class by adding [the second nodeConfiguration](http://answers.ros.org/question/186340/using-rosjava-in-android-i-execute-2-nodes-but-only-one-node-connects-at-a-time/)
- Use CompressedImagePublisher from org.ros.android.view.camera.
- Write rosjava publisher from scratch as this [link](http://rosjava.github.io/rosjava_core/latest/getting_started.html#publishers-and-subscribers)

Any idea or suggestion would be much appreciated!
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265716/adding-an-image-publishing-node-to-the-android_tutorial_image_transport/) by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-07-10**:
Hi @hulkbv, would you mind detailing why you failed using CompressedImagePublisher from android.view.camera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @jubeira,
I made it work on the weekend. The mistake I made is that I forgot to setCamera and releaseCamera (due to the lack of android dev experience), these methods come from CameraPreviewView. Anw, thanks for asking :)

---

Originally posted by [hulkbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/26123/hulkbv/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0